# Pixel C not found by Android Studio/ADB

Tags: android, android-studio

I got some Pixel C tablets and Nexus 5x phones in to test with this week, and got some USB-A to USB-C cables to use the tablets/phones for debugging from Android Studio. Now, the problem I'm having is, the Nexus 5x's are being detected fine by Android Studio, but the Pixel C's are not. The Pixel C's are being detected by the OS, as the device shows up in Windows Explorer, but I get nothing when looking at the Android Device Manager. USB Debugging IS enabled on both devices, and I've tried using the various USB settings (MTP/PTP) with no luck. Any help would be appreciated, and I've attached a picture showing the devices in Explorer and Android Studio. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Open device manager, find the ADB device for your pixel C and then manually select the google drivers from your sdk/extras folder.

Comment: Thanks, you got me on the right track. I had to click 'Update Driver...' > 'Browse My Computer for driver software' > 'Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer' and chose 'Android Device' and now it's working. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to click 'Update Driver...' > 'Browse My Computer for driver software' > 'Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer' and chose 'Android Device' and now it's working.
This is really perfect solution

Comment: Do you have an idea for Ubuntu?? @Amey

Comment: Click "Update Driver" where?